# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 4):

This election was ended early due to special circumstances of limited participation, as indicated on [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78411/moderator-elections):

> As Grace Note mentioned, the election system was not set up to handle a case of low participation like this. We have gone ahead and ended the election early on WebApps - congrats to the winners there.
>
> As rare as we hope it is, this scenario is likely something we'll review to better handle in the future.
>
> <sup><sub>[Moderator Elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78411/moderator-elections/78437#78437)</sub></sup>